# Can I find which CQL rules are violated by a class

Tags: ndepend

I am trying to use NDepend in code review process. The one thing I want to solve is to check if newly created classes are valid from the point of CQL rules.

I have plenty of legacy code and there numerous fields/classes/methods that violates CQL rules. But I want to find only these rules which are violated by a particular class which was newly created by a developer and which I want to review.

Is there a way to find all CQL rules violated by a particular class, so I could fix them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can compare two analysis and select new classes with the CQL condition "WasAdded".

```
Select Classes Where WasAdded
```

Other attributes to compare two versions are

- WasRemoved
- CodeWasChanged

Check out [CQL Documentation](http://www.ndepend.com/CQL.htm#_Toc225920143) and [this article](http://codebetter.com/patricksmacchia/2008/01/01/ensure-the-quality-of-the-code-that-will-be-developed-this-year/) from Patrick.

Comment: Thanks! That what I was really looking for!